# Inserting HTML with JS

Tags: javascript, html, insert, setinterval

I'm just a bit stumped about something at the moment I have the following code which works as expected, everything is fine with it. However I would like to make some minor changes as I would like the following function to be able to insert html markup within the text itself i.e;

```
var str = "Let's get Future Ready!";
var split = str.split("");
var counter = 0;

var SI = setInterval(function() {

    var typeText = $('.typetext');
    typeText.append(split[counter]);
    counter++
    if(counter == str.length){clearInterval(SI)}

},100)
```

So at the moment, this function takes an array, split's and then using the setInterval method I have iterated over the string length. This allows for the text to look like it's being typed.

As you can see though, my initial value of str is 'var str = "Let's get Future Ready!";'

However I would like to add a break to my str value 'var str = "Let's get 
 Future Ready!"'

First of is it possible? Secondly, if anyone could offer me some advice I would be grateful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you want a line break in the HTML-Text you insert?

Insert a

```
<br />
```

into the array at the spot where you want the text to break.For inserting a element into an array look at the splice() function of javascript:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

example with your code:

```
var str = "Let's get Future Ready!";
var split = str.split("");
var counter = 0;
split = split.splice(18, 0, "<br />");
```

Comment: Hey juli0r that is correct. At the moment it reads the whole text on one line which is what I wanted it to do. But now I would like to add a <br/> after get and before Future so that it type's on a new line. Is this possible? Thank you.

Comment: I edited my post. Array.splice() is the thing you are looking for I believe. You can easily add an element into an array at the index you specify.

Comment: Thank you for your help juli0r +1

Answer (score 6):

My suggestion is to replace the `|` character with `<br>` when doing the loop. Check it out here: https://jsfiddle.net/s04zbfcc/

```
var str = "Let's get|Future Ready!";
var split = str.split("");
var counter = 0;

var SI = setInterval(function() {

    var typeText = $('.typetext');

    typeText.append(split[counter] == '|' ? '<br>' : split[counter]);
    counter++

    if(counter == str.length) {
        clearInterval(SI)
    }

},100)
```

Comment: Thank you for your feedback I appreciate it, I have used juli0r's method as it was the most convenient. Thanks!

Comment: This is much better as you are no longer dependent of what string you want to display

Comment: Question is what happens if the text changes? Or if you want to do two linebreaks. Investing in good, maintainable and flexible code is always a good idea.

Comment: Oh wow, I literally only just realised that. This is actually amazing haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check the below snippet. *Explanation in comments*

```js
var str = "Let's get Future Ready!";
var split = str.split("");
var counter = 0;

var SI = setInterval(function() {

    var typeText = $('.typetext');
    typeText.append(split[counter]);
    counter++
    if(typeText.text()=="Let's get")//check the text and see if it  has Let's get
      typeText.append("<br/>");//if yes append br there
    if(counter == str.length){
      clearInterval(SI);
    }

},100)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="typetext"></div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the feedback, all of these methods that everyone has suggested seem applicable to my situation! Thanks once again.